# How to restrict access token usage with in an api

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I use Google Drive as a storage. There are many files in one GD. This GD contains files of multiple users. When some user wants to access his file, I generate access token for specific file. However, this access token can be used to list all files on GD, including others files. I want to put restrict to files.list API on Google Drive. Is there any way to disable files.list API?
I use following code to get refresh token for read only access to files

```
 public static async Task<string> generateReaderRefreshToken(string clientID, string clientSecret)
    { 
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly  };

        ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientID,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        };
        UserCredential crdls = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
         (secrets,
         scopes,
         "user",
         CancellationToken.None);
         
      
        return crdls.Token.RefreshToken;
    }
```

Comment: What about if you share with each user the file to which he should have acess and then let him programmatically access this file auhenticating as himself?

Comment: @ziganotschka For that each user should have gmail account. That's not good

Comment: You can also think about using a service account that could only read / list files explicitly shared with the service acocunt.

Comment: @ziganotschka In my case there is one application which generates read/write access tokens to view or upload files for client apps. I don't understand much about service account, but can it solve my problem in my case?

Comment: See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) for Google Service accounts. Basically, when you create service accounts credentials, code can be run on behalf of the servie account. You can share files with the service account as if he were a (GSuite!) user and the advantage is that the service acocunt would only have access to the files explicitly shard with it, even if you give it an ample scope.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your auth code we need to see how you are authenticating.

Comment: @DaImTo I have edited. That code is used to generate refresh token which later used to generate read only access tokens

Comment: @support_ms i edited my answer to give you a little advice on your application design.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks. It seems I need to learn more about service account

Comment: Service accounts wont do 100% of what you want to do but it may help you limit what you are doing.

Comment: @DaImTo can service accounts be created programmatically and without limit? For example can I create 10000 service accounts for one drive?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the way Oauth2 works is for the most part you get access to the full drive account when you get access.  With the exception of drive.file which gives you access to all the files created by your application.

Valid google drive scopes

[image]

## Oauth2 user account

For a moment lets assume that you are using a normal oauth client, and using a refresh token to create these access tokens.  when you authncated the application the and were shown a consent screen I am gong to assume that you requested access with the following scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files
```

This scope gives you full access to a drive account. It does not limit how much access you have you can see everything and do anything.  Within the limits of the drive api of course.  Its not going to let you make coffee.

## oauth2 service account

Now lets assume that you are using a service account.  A service account is bound by the same rules as a normal user.  When you authenticated the service account.  you probably also used the  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive it would make sense that the service account would then be able to control all its files.  When the service account creates access tokens those access tokens are still going to have access to all the files on the drive account

## drive file scope

There is one other scope that cold help you but not as much as you would hope that being the following scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file  View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app
```

This scope would limit access to files created by your application.  Your application is denoted by the client id or rather the project you created on google developer console.  So with this scope you would only have access to files created by this application and not others.

## anwser

So while it would be really nice to be able to limit which files an access token grants access to unfortunately thats not possible with the exception of limiting it to all the files created by your application using drive.file.  Nor is there a way for you to limit what methods the API can do with a access token.

Access tokens are like keys as long as they are valid they can do anything there permissions grant them access to.

## Your code.

The way you seam to have created your application is that you have a console application which you run once to return to you a refresh token that grants read access to "A google drive account".   You are then using this refresh token to create new access tokens to allow others to access your account.   The issue with this is that you are giving them acess to everything on this account. You cant hide anything from them they have full access.

What you should consider doing is creating a service account.  A service account is a dummy user.  It has its own drive account.  There are two ways to use the service account.

1. you can upload files directly to the service accounts drive account.  Then using the service acccount to serve the files to your users. As it also has access to read from its account.
2. You can create a directory on this "otherDrive" account that you are currently using and share it with the service account just like you would share a directory with any other user. The service account will then have access to read from that and only that directory keeping the rest of the drive account secret.

You might find my article on service accounts interesting [Google Developer console service account](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)  I also have an example for service account with .net you might find useful [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs)

Comment: There are several questions. Let's say I have one application (created with google console) and 10 user GD account. My application has access to all 10 users GD files. If I create service account it should be on my application account (at the same google account which I created my application). So, does this service account use 10 users drive to store/read files?

Comment: Service accounts are only for accessing an account you the developer has access to. If you need access to a users google drive account then you will need to use Oauth2 and request access to their account.

Comment: It seems service account isn't that thing which is going to help me.

Comment: No you can't make them programmatically I don't know what the limit is but there will be a limit on how many users you can share a folder with.